# make firefox's quick find shortcut working in alternate layout as well

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I like very much  quick find shortcut in Firefox - "/" to search on the page.
But when I switch to alternate layout (Cyrillic) it stops working.
How can I make it works regardless of keyboard layout?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe this question belongs on Firefox's site... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/new